# How can calls to Histogram<T> and Counter<T> be verified in unit tests?

Tags: c#, open-telemetry

I'd like to make a assertions in unit tests to confirm that the telemetry meters `Histogram<T>` and `Counter<T>` are being called. If I have a reference to the meter instance that the unit test code is calling, is there a way to inspect it and confirm that the `Record` or `Add` methods are being called or not?

Comment: You'll have to mock them (and/or proxy them) - I'm not an Open-Telemetry user, but if `Histogram<T>` and `Counter<T>` don't have `interface` types you can mock them with then you may need to resort to low-level CLR hacking to intercept those method calls.

Comment: They're meters, so read them with a MetricsListener. It's the same with Activities. Both are explicit testing ports for your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't test them directly, however, I don't think that's the way that they should be tested.

You can create a `MetricsListener` that can listen to a specific metric and verify that you get the right outcome rather than the right value is passed.  With this, you can pass in a Metric with a specific auto-generated name that you can assert against. Similar to the way that you'd test for `Activity`.